# Is it possible to change bspwm binds to work like tmux binds?

Tags: tmux, bspwm, sxhkd

I come from tmux and I was wondering if its possible to configure sxhkd and bspwm to have binds just like it. For example,

Assuming my `C-w` is my prefix rather than the default `C-b` tmux prefix

```
C-w h # move to left pane
C-w j # move to bottom pane
C-w k # move to upper pane
C-w l # move to right pane
C-w v # vertical split pane
C-w n # horizontal split pane
```

I was reading how 2 keys and one modifier isn't possible in bspwm and sxhkd. If so, what other tiling window manager and hotkey daemon combination can I use to achieve this ?

I tried this but the `h` key seems to be the only key that works. I don't want to write those two lines of code for every key if I don't have to

```
ctrl + w ; {h,j,k,l)
    bspc node -{f,s} {west,south,north,east}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rowantran/vim-bspwm-navigator

By using this plugin and adding a couple of changes to my init.vim, I was able to achieve the results I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer about the "other" tiling window manager.

[i3](https://i3wm.org) allows you to define modes which sounds like what you want:

```
# Press $mod+o followed by either f, t, Escape or Return to launch firefox,
# thunderbird or return to the default mode, respectively.
set $mode_launcher Launch: [f]irefox [t]hunderbird
bindsym $mod+o mode "$mode_launcher"

mode "$mode_launcher" {
    bindsym f exec firefox
    bindsym t exec thunderbird

    bindsym Escape mode "default"
    bindsym Return mode "default"
}
```

see https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#binding_modes